# Probability of independent games

Tags: probability

David plays a series of independent games. In each game David can:

1) win 1\$ with a probability $p$,  or
2) lose 1\$ with a probability $1-p$, or
3) win 1\$ (with probability $p$) and then immediately lose 2\$ (in the same turn) with a probability $q$.

$X_{n}$ is the profit of David after $n$ games.

My first question was what is the distribution of $X_{n}$.

I think that $X$~$B(n, p(1-q))$ meaning it is a binomic distribution with $n$ games where the probability to win is $p$ multiplied by the probability not to lose 2\$ after a win ($1-q$). Is this correct?

My second question was: if it is known that after the 8th game David had 0\$, what is the probability that David had 1\$ after the 5th game?

I think that if $A$ is "David had 0\$ after the 8th game" and $B$ is "David had 1\$ after the $5th$ game", then I calculate $P(B/A)$ like this:

$\frac{{3 \choose 2}(p-pq)(1-p+pq)^2 {5 \choose 3}(p-pq)^3(1-p+pq)^2}{{8 \choose 4}(p-pq)^4(1-p+pq)^4}$

Where the numerator is $P(A \cap B)$ - I chose $2$ games to lose out of $3$ multiplied by $1$ win and $1$ loss and then I chose $3$ out of $5$ games to win multipled by $3$ wins and $2$ losses. Is this correct? Or am I not even close?

Comment: I don't understand the game.  What does "If David wins $1$ he can lose $2$ with probability $q$" mean?  What exactly are the rules of the game?

Comment: For example - first turn I won 1\$ (probability p) and next turn I have a q chance to lose 2\$

Comment: So the games are different each turn?  Then you have to specify how the probability changes each round.

Comment: As it stands the rules of the game are not at all clear.  If the probability or the stakes shifts from round to round, then $D's$ performance will be path dependent, so simple counting arguments like those you suggest do not apply.

Comment: I am sorry, you were right. The question means that if David won 1 dollar (probability p), he can immediately in the same turn lose 2 dollars (probability q). Can you help me with this question now?

Comment: The rules are still not clear.  I think (but don't know) that you are trying to say that there are three possible outcomes in a round).  But if that's the case, then just state clearly what the three outcomes are and what the probabilities of each might be.

Comment: Yes. The outcome to just win 1\$, the outcome to win 1\$ and then immediately lose 2\$, and the outcome just to lose 1$. I edited the question. Is this clear now?

Comment: No.  Your three probabilities add to $1+q>1$.  I think you mean:  there is a $p\times (1-q)$ chance of winning $1$ and a $(1-p)+p\times q$ chance of losing $1$.  But in that case, you should just throw out the "extra turn" and consider a weighted coin with probability $\psi=p\times (1-q)$.

Comment: Yes. So I answered correctly? And you can edit my question if you want...

Comment: I didn't look at your answer...I was confused by the game.  Looking at it now...I agree with part 1.  Not sure about part $2$...the $p,q$ notation really messes it up.  Can you recast the formula using $\psi=p\times (1-q)$?

Comment: It's already there: $p - pq$

Comment: The problem seems clear enough:  after round $5$, I might have $\pm 5, \pm 3, \pm 1$.  $\pm 5$ is out (as I can't win or lose $5$ in three rounds).  So you just have to handle $\pm 3, \pm 1$.

Comment: Yeah, but you have $p,q$ in other combinations as well.  Over complicates what should be a simple formula.

Comment: Never mind, I sorted it out (in my mind at least).  Looks good!